# Building a keyboard controlled game in pygame. I'm getting an indentation error but I dont know why

Tags: python, pygame, indentation

This is my game so far. I was able to display the Player and make it move with the keyboard. On a separate program I displayed the Enemy class randomly within the range. When I combined the two programs I started getting a bunch of indentation errors. If I fix one, another one pops ups. Please help!

```
import pygame
import os
import random

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 100, 0)


# This class represents the bar at the bottom that the player controls
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player_one.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.width = 15
        self.height = 15
        self.x = 940
        self.y = 240

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            if self.y < 470:
                self.y += self.height
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            if self.y > 0:
                self.y -= self.height
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if self.x < 940:
                self.x += self.width
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if self.x > 0:
                self.x -= self.width

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

class Enemy(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        image_rect = image.get_rect()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.centery = y

    def draw(self, screen):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = random.randint(60, 220+1), random.randint( 0, 475+1)

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Best Football Game Ever!')

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))

        self.multi_enemies = []

        for i in range(1, 4):
            enemy = Enemy("enemy_"+str(i)+".png")
            enemy.update()
            self.multi_enemies.append(enemy)

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        running = True

        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        running = False

                for enemy in self.multi_enemies:
                    enemy.update()

            #---updates----

            # place for updates

            # --- draws ---

            for enemy in self.multi_enemies:
                enemy.draw(self.screen)

            for x in range(60,940,35):
                pygame.draw.line(screen, white, [x, 0], [x, 500], 1)

            player.handle_keys()

            self.screen.fill(green)

            pygame.display.flip()

            clock.tick(20)  

    pygame.quit()

Game().run()
```

Comment: Why do you have `pygame.quit()` as part of the class body and not in any method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing tabs with spaces for indentation. The only way this "works" is if you have your tabstop set to 8

Since nearly everyone uses 4 spaces for indentation, a tab looks like two levels of indentation, but Python only counts it as one

---

Here tabs are highlighted in yellow:

[image]

Comment: That's not how Python treats tabs. It converts them to enough spaces to hit the next 8-space indentation level.

Comment: @user2357112, that's what it means to have the tabstops set to 8

Comment: "Since nearly everyone uses 4 spaces for indentation, a tab looks like two levels of indentation, but Python only counts it as one" - this description isn't consistent with Python's behavior. The number of indentation levels a tab counts as depends on the context; it may be one, two, an invalid indentation level, or up to eight if the indentation is really weird.

Comment: I fixed the indents. But now it says: File "BestDamnGame.py", line 67, in __init__
    enemy = Enemy("enemy_"+str(i)+".png")
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) I never got this error when I ran it elsewhere

Comment: @user2242927: The error is because `Enemy.__init__()` is defined to take no additional arguments (other than the default `self` one for methods) and you're trying to pass it one -- a string -- by calling `Enemy("enemy_"+str(i)+".png")`.

Comment: You have ommitted the `image` argument: `class Enemy(object):

    def __init__(self,image):`  which is used in the next line below to load an image.

Answer (score 0):

Edit-Select All

then go to

Format- Untabify

That should fix your problem